# How to properly use custom config file in C# console application

Tags: c#, config

I am writing a simple console application that will, in the end, open a web browser page.
I want the browser name to be saved in an external configuration file, so that the user can manually change it to their favourite. *(Though I am open to a different approach, this was the one deemed best for the uses of the application).*

However, I cannot use the `App.config` file, as it is located in the application folder, which ***cannot*** be accessed by non-admin users. *(Moving the application folder is not an option, as it will be installed under Program Files).*

Therefore I would like to have the application use another .config file, located in the user's Documents (or any other accessible folder), though I haven't found any "canonical" way to tell my application to look for that file, instead of the default `App.config`, and still be able to use the `ConfigurationManager` like this:

```cs
browser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("browser");
```

Is there a way to tell my application to load a different `.config` file, or should I open it as a normal text file and handle the parsing?

Edit: I am using .NET Core 3.1 and VisualStudio 2019

Comment: Consider application settings? https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings

Comment: [You can do this:]( https://bhrnjica.net/2016/01/30/using-external-config-files-in-net-applications/)

Comment: Sorry, added some clarifications - @insane_developer this looks promising, I'll check it out

Comment: @WSLab I guess you can still use an app.config in .NET Core 3.x. I usually go with the appsettings.json configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For example, this is your appconfig:

```
"Parameter": {
    "DbConnectionRead": ""
}
```

and you can use `ConfigurationBuilder` in C# class like below example:

```cs
string ReaderConnectionString;
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

ReaderConnectionString = builder.Build()
                                .GetSection("Parameter")
                                .GetSection("DbConnectionRead")
                                .Value;
```

I hope this is useful to you.